# MySQL syntax to expand links from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join

This seems quite basic but I'm not sure of the vocab behind the question, which makes it hard to look up online.

I've got two tables:

- `sentences` (fields: id, language, author), which contains sentences in two languages
- `links` (fields: id1, id2) which refers to sentences inside of the `sentences` table. Meaning: each sentence referred to in id2 is a translation of sentence id1.

What I want is to display the `links` table but *expand it* by displaying the sentence in each language too.
What would the technical term be for this 'expand' operation?

i.e.: instead of just:

```
id1     id2 
1276    4569
1283    3098
1284    3099
```

I'm trying to get something in the lines of:

```
id1     id2     sentence1    sentence(2)
1276    4569    Hi           Salut          
1283    3098    I love pie.  J'adore les gâteaux.
1284    3099    Wanna drink? Tu veux biore quelque chose?
```

Here is what I got so far... It's something but I'm still missing the whole sentence for id2.

```
SELECT sentences.*, links.* FROM links
JOIN sentences ON links.id1 = sentences.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s2.*,s1.*, links.* FROM links
JOIN sentences as s1 ON links.id1 = s1.id
Join sentences as s2 on links.id2 = s2.id
```

Comment: pls, if it is what you looking for mark it as answer

Comment: Thank you. I never use variables in my queries and this example shows me why they're sometimes a must.

Comment: @FabienSnauwaert: Please don't confuse `variables` and `aliases`, they're two different things. ;)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid problems in your programming language(php?) you should not use * in the query.
Just list all columns you need in the SELECT and give the columns in table s2 an alias